# Prometheus HTTP metrics for react frontend application

Tags: reactjs, express, prometheus

I am developing a react web application and would like to add some http metrics like response time, status code for each request etc. I am using Prom-client to achieve this. The server.js file is given below

```
const express = require('express')
const Prometheus = require('prom-client');
const favicon = require('express-favicon');
const path = require('path');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8082
const metricsInterval = Prometheus.collectDefaultMetrics()

const httpRequestDurationMicroseconds = new Prometheus.Histogram({
 name: 'http_request_duration_ms',
 help: 'Duration of HTTP requests in ms',
 labelNames: ['method', 'route', 'code'],
 buckets: [0.10, 5, 15, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]  
})

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/build/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
 res.locals.startEpoch = Date.now()
 next()
})

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
 res.json({ message: 'Hello World!' })
 next()
 }, Math.round(Math.random() * 200))
})

app.get('/bad', (req, res, next) => {
next(new Error('My Error'))
})

app.get('/metrics', (req, res) => {
res.setHeader('Content-Type', Prometheus.register.contentType)
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); 
res.end(Prometheus.register.metrics())
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
 res.statusCode = 500
 res.json({ error: err.message })
 next()
})

 app.use((req, res, next) => {
 const responseTimeInMs = Date.now() - res.locals.startEpoch

 httpRequestDurationMicroseconds
 .labels(req.method, req.path, res.statusCode)
 .observe(responseTimeInMs)

  next()
 })

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
})

// Graceful shutdown
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
clearInterval(metricsInterval)

server.close((err) => {
if (err) {
  console.error(err)
  process.exit(1)
}

process.exit(0)
})
})
```

This config is giving the following results for localhost:8082/metrics

```
# HELP http_request_duration_ms Duration of HTTP requests in ms
# TYPE http_request_duration_ms histogram
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="0.1",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="5",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="15",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="50",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="100",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="200",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="300",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="400",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="500",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_bucket{le="+Inf",method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
http_request_duration_ms_sum{method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 0
http_request_duration_ms_count{method="GET",route="/clients",code="200"} 1
```

The metrics don't show up 5** errors and it shows only 200 as the status code for every request. How to register my http calls to the prometheus client?

Comment: Did you find any response for this question? Can you plz take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69373397/how-should-get-api-call-logs-in-react-project-with-promethus

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below configuration

```
npm install express-prom-bundle
```

metrics.js

```
import express_prom_bundle from 'express-prom-bundle';
const metricsMiddleware = express_prom_bundle({
  includeStatusCode: true,
  includeMethod: true,
  includePath: true,
  customLabels: {
    project_name: 'groot',
    project_type: 'nodejs',
  },
  metricType: 'summary',
  promClient: {
    collectDefaultMetrics: {},
  },
});

export default metricsMiddleware;
```

inside your server.js you can add

```
app.use(metricsMiddleware);
```